# How to take particular key value pairs from json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a large amount of data in JSON array format.
A shorter version of which is as shown below

```
[{"Item": "Item1", "Unit CP": 100, "Unit SP": 150, "Quantity": 1, "TotalSP": 150},
{"Item": "Item2", "Unit CP": 50, "Unit SP": 70, "Quantity": 7, "TotalSP": 490},
{"Item": "Item3", "Unit CP": 1000, "Unit SP": 900, "Quantity": 1, "TotalSP": 900},
{"Item": "Item4", "Unit CP": 200, "Unit SP": 500, "Quantity": 2, "TotalSP": 1000},
{"Item": "Item5", "Unit CP": 300, "Unit SP": 311, "Quantity": 3, "TotalSP": 933},
{"Item": "Item6", "Unit CP": 750, "Unit SP": 755, "Quantity": 2, "TotalSP": 1510}]
```

i want to get a JSON array of objects with keys "Item" and "Unit SP" only i.e

```
[{"Item": "Item1", "Unit SP": 150},
{"Item": "Item2", "Unit SP": 70},
{"Item": "Item3", "Unit SP": 900},
{"Item": "Item4", "Unit SP": 500},
{"Item": "Item5", "Unit SP": 311},
{"Item": "Item6", "Unit SP": 755}]
```

Is there a simpler way to do so in javascript without parsing through the whole array?
Thanks in advance

Comment: "*without parsing through the whole array*" impossible - if you want to do something with each element, then you need to visit each element.

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.map()` to extract the properties you want from each element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `Proxy` to get them individually:

```
let proxy = new Proxy(data,   {get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
      let obj = Reflect.get(...arguments);
      return { "Item": obj["Item"], "Unit CP": obj["Unit CP"] };
  } });
```

```js
let data = [{"Item": "Item1", "Unit CP": 100, "Unit SP": 150, "Quantity": 1, "TotalSP": 150},
{"Item": "Item2", "Unit CP": 50, "Unit SP": 70, "Quantity": 7, "TotalSP": 490},
{"Item": "Item3", "Unit CP": 1000, "Unit SP": 900, "Quantity": 1, "TotalSP": 900},
{"Item": "Item4", "Unit CP": 200, "Unit SP": 500, "Quantity": 2, "TotalSP": 1000},
{"Item": "Item5", "Unit CP": 300, "Unit SP": 311, "Quantity": 3, "TotalSP": 933},
{"Item": "Item6", "Unit CP": 750, "Unit SP": 755, "Quantity": 2, "TotalSP": 1510}]

let proxy = new Proxy(data,   {get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
      let obj = Reflect.get(...arguments);
      return { "Item": obj["Item"], "Unit SP": obj["Unit SP"] };
  } });
  
 console.log( proxy[0] )
```

---

Or adjust `Symbol.iterator` to only return back what's needed while iterating.

```
data[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
 let i = -1;
 while(++i < data.length) {
 yield { "Item": data[i]["Item"], "Unit CP": data[i]["Unit CP"] }
 }
}
```

```js
let data = [{"Item": "Item1", "Unit CP": 100, "Unit SP": 150, "Quantity": 1, "TotalSP": 150},
{"Item": "Item2", "Unit CP": 50, "Unit SP": 70, "Quantity": 7, "TotalSP": 490},
{"Item": "Item3", "Unit CP": 1000, "Unit SP": 900, "Quantity": 1, "TotalSP": 900},
{"Item": "Item4", "Unit CP": 200, "Unit SP": 500, "Quantity": 2, "TotalSP": 1000},
{"Item": "Item5", "Unit CP": 300, "Unit SP": 311, "Quantity": 3, "TotalSP": 933},
{"Item": "Item6", "Unit CP": 750, "Unit SP": 755, "Quantity": 2, "TotalSP": 1510}]

data[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
 let i = -1;
 while(++i < data.length) {
 yield { "Item": data[i]["Item"], "Unit SP": data[i]["Unit SP"] }
 }
}

for(let obj of data) console.log(obj);
```

---

Probably, as you've likely supposed, the easiest way is just to use `Array.prototype.map` and create a new instance of data as you'd like it.

The only reason I could see you *not* going this route is if you needed to use the same reference, but as you haven't mentioned that I would almost always suggest this:

```
data.map(obj => ({ "Item": obj["Item"], "Unit SP": obj["Unit SP"] }) );
```

```js
let data = [{"Item": "Item1", "Unit CP": 100, "Unit SP": 150, "Quantity": 1, "TotalSP": 150},
{"Item": "Item2", "Unit CP": 50, "Unit SP": 70, "Quantity": 7, "TotalSP": 490},
{"Item": "Item3", "Unit CP": 1000, "Unit SP": 900, "Quantity": 1, "TotalSP": 900},
{"Item": "Item4", "Unit CP": 200, "Unit SP": 500, "Quantity": 2, "TotalSP": 1000},
{"Item": "Item5", "Unit CP": 300, "Unit SP": 311, "Quantity": 3, "TotalSP": 933},
{"Item": "Item6", "Unit CP": 750, "Unit SP": 755, "Quantity": 2, "TotalSP": 1510}]

let transformed = data.map(obj => ({ "Item": obj["Item"], "Unit SP": obj["Unit SP"] }) );

console.log(transformed);
```

---

### Aside:

You'll notice that these all get the data in some way and then extrapolate a new Object from it. That's just how *data transformations* work. If your only option is to get the data as-is from wherever you're getting it from, there's no getting around it.

If this is a resource that you're pulling from( like a REST API ) and you have access to alter what information is going out, that's where you'd start if you don't want to alter your data on the client-side.

Otherwise some combination of the above will likely have to do.